# Como transformar parte de uma coluna em outra com data.table?

Tags: r, data.rable-r

Tenho um data.table com uma coluna que possui o código dos municípios (6 primeiros caracteres) e o nome dos municípios (demais caracteres).

Eu gostaria de separá-los, usando data.table.

Em data.frame, seria assim:

```r
pop_mun_total$cod_mun <- str_sub(pop_mun_total$mun,start=1, end=6)
```

Isso também funciona em data.table, mas ele possui alguma função específica?

Exemplo do data.table:

```r
pop_mun_total <- data.table(mun=c("110001 Alta Floresta D'Oeste", "110037 Alto Alegre dos Parecis","110040 Alto Paraíso", "110034 Alvorada D'Oeste", "110002 Ariquemes","110045 Buritis", "110003 Cabixi", "110060 Cacaulândia", "110004 Cacoal","110070 Campo Novo de Rondônia", "110080 Candeias do Jamari","110090 Castanheiras", "110005 Cerejeiras", "110092 Chupinguaia","110006 Colorado do Oeste", "110007 Corumbiara", "110008 Costa Marques","110094 Cujubim", "110009 Espigão D'Oeste", "110100 Governador Jorge Teixeira"))
```

Como eu gostaria que ficasse:

```r
cod_mun    mun
110001     Alta Floresta D'Oeste
110037     Alto Alegre dos Parecis    
...        ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A seguinte solução usa `tstrsplit`, uma combinação de `transpose` e de `strsplit`. Mas antes de separar a coluna em duas, substitui o primeiro espaço por um `"_"`, uma vez que este caráter não pode ser código nem nome de município.
Como já existe uma coluna `mun`, a nova coluna é criada no fim.

```
pop_mun_total[, mun := sub(" ", "_", mun)]
pop_mun_total[, c("cod_mun", "mun") := tstrsplit(mun, "_", fixed = TRUE)]

head(pop_mun_total)
#                       mun cod_mun
#1:   Alta Floresta D'Oeste  110001
#2: Alto Alegre dos Parecis  110037
#3:            Alto Paraíso  110040
#4:        Alvorada D'Oeste  110034
#5:               Ariquemes  110002
#6:                 Buritis  110045
```

Juntando tudo numa só instrução.

```
pop_mun_total[, c("cod_mun", "mun") := tstrsplit(sub(" ", "_", mun), "_", fixed = TRUE)]
```

Para ter as colunas na ordem da pergunta, pode ser utilizada qualquer uma das duas instruções abaixo.

```
pop_mun_total[, 2:1]
pop_mun_total[, c("cod_mun", "mun")]
```

Comment: Ao invés de substituir o primeiro espaço por "_", pode usar uma expressão regular que identifica o primeiro espaço depois de dígitos: `tstrsplit(mun, "(?<=\\d) ", perl = TRUE)`